# Change ownership or permissions on only directories or files, recursively

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm trying to set permissions/ownership on either directories or files, recursively within a given directory, without changing the other.

E.g. I have directory /web where I want to set all the directories to 775, but the files to 664.

Is there a way to do this easily?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For files:

```
$ find /path/to/directory -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 664
```

For directories:

```
$ find /path/to/directory -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 775
```

Comment: `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` in case there are spaces or newlines in filenames.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the correction, Dennis. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

As a supplement to ErikA's answer, if I were to guess the reason you wanted to do this, you were looking to add the write bit for "group".  If that's the case, you can avoid the two-command dance and just run:

```
chmod -R g+w /path/to/directory
```

Comment: Thanks, though it was the split between files or directories which was important.